# Why after using collect on a streamed list without generic returns an object?

Tags: java, generics, stream

Why the following code produces an object instead of a list ?

```
Object listWithoutGeneric = new ArrayList().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(trying to substitude  **Object** listWithoutGeneric = ...  with **List** listWithoutGeneric = ...  produces compilation error)

while the following sample returns a list?

```
List listWithDefaultGeneric = new ArrayList<>().stream()
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your terminal operation - `collect` - has the following signature:

```
<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector)
```

i.e. it returns an instance of type `R`.

The `toList()` `Collector` returns a `Collector<T, ?, List<T>>`, so `R` in that case is a `List<T>`.

However, if you are creating a `Stream` from a raw `ArrayList`, the `Stream` is also raw, so `R` becomes `Object`.

In other words, `<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector)` becomes `Object collect(Collector collector)`, so `collect` returns an `Object`.

Hence `new ArrayList().stream().collect(Collectors.toList())` returns an `Object`.

Comment: I'm probably slow at connecting the dots here... but why `Object` instead of `List<Object>` (or `List` at worst)? I'd conceive of *raw* `Stream` as more like a `Stream<Object>` (of course with its associated problems)

Comment: @ernest_k when you use a raw Stream, you lose all generic type information in any Stream methods you are using, so `<R, A> R collect(Collector<? super T, A, R> collector)` becomes `Object collect(Collector collector)`. a `Stream<Object>` is what you get in the second snippet (`new ArrayList<>().stream()...`), not the first.

Comment: Right, I see (the dramatic effect comes from the loss of generic information on the collector, rather than on the stream, even though the latter causes the former)